# Android: View Pager of fragments that contain a scroll view, how to reset the scroll view to the top of the screen in OnPause

Tags: android

**Background**

FragmentList contains a view pager with an underlying FragmentStatePagerAdapter to show pages of FragmentDetail

FragmentDetail contains a scroll view

**What i want to do**

As you swipe, i want the previous FragmentDetail scroll position reset to the top. At the moment, when you swipe back to it, the scroll position goes back to where you left off.

E.g. I am on page 1 of view pager, i scroll to bottom of the current detail fragment. I then go to next page. Finally i go back to the first page, i want the scroll to be at the top and not where i left it

**I tried the following**

in OnPause of fragment detail, i tried the following code

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

I also tried the following

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            }
        });
    }
```

Also put the scrollTo code in a runnable is well.

Does not scroll to the top

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `onPause()`; you will drive yourself insane.

The best way I have found to do this sort of thing is override `setPrimaryItem()` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` subclass.  `setPrimaryItem()` is called whenever a fragment is displayed by the `ViewPager`.

Let's say you have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ResettableFragment {
    public void reset();
}
```

and so your fragment implementation is:

```
@Override
public void reset() {
    mScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

In your `FragmentPagerAdapter` subclass, create a member

```
private ResettableFragment mLast;
```

and override `setPrimaryItem()` like this:

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

    if (mLast != null) {
        mLast.reset();
        mLast = null;
    }

    if (object instanceof ResettableFragment) {
        mLast = (ResettableFragment) object;
    }
}
```

Some people prefer to register a `ViewPager.OnPageChangListener` which overrides `onPageSelected()` to do the reset logic instead of overriding `setPrimaryItem()` in the adapter.

That might look something like this:

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (position == POSITION_OF_PAGE_TO_RESET + 1 ||
                    position == POSITION_OF_PAGE_TO_RESET - 1) {
                FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
                ResettableFragment fragment = (ResettableFragment) adapter.getItem(position);
                fragment.reset();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would you be kind to show other implementation? I couldn't find a `onPageChangeListener` code for this question. This one didn't work for me.

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 please see my updated answer. The `OnPageChangeListener` is actually harder to do since you have to access the fragment next to the current page.  I would recommend that if you have problems getting this to work, post a new question with your current code so that the community can better assist you.